# Incorporating read / write classes into a basic GUI login

Tags: java, swing

I am a complete noob, have been learning Java for just a couple of weeks.  As part of a piece of code that I have been tasked to write I have to create a Logon page, that takes in a username and password that is then checked against a txt file that holds the information.  Once verified the user then would proceed to the GUI based game that I need to create.

I have the following pieces of code that I know all work individually, what I am struggling to do is bring them all together to work as one.

Login Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Login 
{
private static JFrame frame;
private static JPanel northPanel;
private static JPanel centerPanel;
private static JPanel southPanel;
private static JLabel headingLabel;
private static JLabel usernameLabel;
private static JLabel passwordLabel;
private static JTextField usernameField;
private static JPasswordField passwordField;
private static JButton loginBtn;

public void start() 
{
    try 
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {

    }

    new Login().buildLogin();
}

private void buildLogin() 
{
    // Build Objects
    frame = new JFrame();
    northPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel = new JPanel();
    southPanel = new JPanel();
    headingLabel = new JLabel();
    usernameLabel = new JLabel();
    passwordLabel = new JLabel();
    usernameField = new JTextField();
    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    loginBtn = new JButton();

    // Labels
    headingLabel.setText("Login");
    headingLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
    headingLabel.setVisible(true);

    usernameLabel.setText("   Username: ");
    usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
    usernameLabel.setVisible(true);

    passwordLabel.setText("   Password: ");
    passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
    passwordLabel.setVisible(true);

    // Buttons
    loginBtn.setText("Login");
    loginBtn.setVisible(true);
    loginBtn.addActionListener(new Validate1());

    // Panels
    northPanel.add(headingLabel);
    northPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    centerPanel.add(usernameLabel);
    centerPanel.add(usernameField);
    centerPanel.add(passwordLabel);
    centerPanel.add(passwordField);
    centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    southPanel.add(loginBtn);

    // JFrame
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, northPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, centerPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, southPanel);
    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

// Validate1 Class
static class Validate1 implements ActionListener 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        String username = null;
        String password = null;

        try 
        {
            username = usernameField.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
            password = passwordField.getText().toUpperCase().trim();

            if (username.equals("") && password.equals("")) 
            {
                usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
            } 
            else 
            {
                if (username.equals("")) 
                {
                    usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    if (password.equals("")) 
                    {
                        usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
                        passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                        passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                        new Login().validate2(username, password);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception validateError) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was an error Class::Login Class Validate1", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}

//Validate2 Method
private void validate2(String getUsername, String getPassword)
{
    String username = null;
    String password = null;

    try
    {
        username = getUsername.toUpperCase();
        password = getPassword.toUpperCase();

        if (username.contains(" ") && password.contains(" ")) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The username and password is invalid", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (username.contains(" ")) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The username is invalid", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } 
            else 
            {
                if (password.contains(" ")) 
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The password is invalid", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    System.out.println("All good!!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in Class::Login Method:valsidate2","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }
}
}
```

Login Main Code:

```
public class Main 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new Login().start();

}

}
```

FileData:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileData 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String file_name = "PATH TO THE TEXT FILE WOULD BE HERE";

    try
    {
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

        for(int i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Sorry, dude - no can do!!!\n" + e.getMessage());
    }

    try
    {
        WriteFile data = new WriteFile(file_name , true );
        data.writeToFile("This is another line of text");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, dude - no can do!!!\n" + e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("Text File Written To");
}

}
```

ReadFile:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile 
{
private String path;

public ReadFile(String file_path)
{
    path = file_path;
}

public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException
{
    FileReader inFile = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(inFile);

    int numOfLines = readLines();
    String[] textData = new String[numOfLines];

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfLines; i++)
    {
        textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
    }

    textReader.close();
    return textData;
}

int readLines() throws IOException
{
    FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

    String aLine;
    int numOfLines = 0;

    while((aLine = bf.readLine()) != null)
    {
        numOfLines++;
    }

    bf.close();

    return numOfLines;
}
}
```

WriteFile:

```
import java.io.*;

public class WriteFile 
{
private String path;
private boolean append_to_file = false;

public WriteFile(String file_path)
{
    path = file_path;
}

public WriteFile(String file_path, boolean append_value)
{
    path = file_path;
    append_to_file = append_value;
}

public void writeToFile(String textLine) throws IOException
{
    FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path, append_to_file);
    PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter(write);

    print_line.printf("%s" + "%n" , textLine);

    print_line.close();
}
}
```

Comment: And what is your specific problem? Do we reall have to go through all this code to understand it?

Comment: Hi Frank, the issue that I am having is bringing them all together.  Individually they all work.  However when I try to get the Login class to use the ReadFile one to check a username and password I am unable to get them to work together.  I would eventually like the Login to read for existing users and write for new ones using the WriteFile.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Concentrate on getting the two classes (log-in & read/write) to work together and factor the other cruft out. Once that is solved, you should understand it well enough to then apply the solution to the larger app. with more classes..

Answer (score 1):

Please see comments in the code. I hope will help you to take it one step forward :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Login {

    //use JDialog to control modality and
    //easier to get a return value
    //private static JFrame frame;
    private static JDialog frame;
    private static JPanel northPanel;
    private static JPanel centerPanel;
    private static JPanel southPanel;
    private static JLabel headingLabel;
    private static JLabel usernameLabel;
    private static JLabel passwordLabel;
    private static JTextField usernameField;
    private static JPasswordField passwordField;
    private static JButton loginBtn;

    //Add a login fail / success flag
    boolean loginSuccess = false;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //have the login process return a fail / success boolean
        boolean loginSuccess = new Login().start();

        System.out.println(loginSuccess);

        //if login is successful run game 
        //else quit / show error / retry 
    }

    //change return type to boolean (fail / success flag)
    public boolean start()
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();   }

        //no need to initialize Login again
        //new Login().buildLogin();
        //use
         buildLogin();

         return loginSuccess;
    }

    private void buildLogin()
    {

        // Build Objects
        frame = new JDialog();  //instead of frame = new JFrame();

        northPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel = new JPanel();
        headingLabel = new JLabel();
        usernameLabel = new JLabel();
        passwordLabel = new JLabel();
        usernameField = new JTextField();
        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        loginBtn = new JButton();

        // Labels
        headingLabel.setText("Login");
        headingLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
        headingLabel.setVisible(true);

        usernameLabel.setText("   Username: ");
        usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        usernameLabel.setVisible(true);

        passwordLabel.setText("   Password: ");
        passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        passwordLabel.setVisible(true);

        // Buttons
        loginBtn.setText("Login");
        loginBtn.setVisible(true);

        //instead of
        //loginBtn.addActionListener(new Validate1());
        //add an action listener and have it run validate1()
        loginBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                validate1();

            }
        });
        // Panels
        northPanel.add(headingLabel);
        northPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        centerPanel.add(usernameLabel);
        centerPanel.add(usernameField);
        centerPanel.add(passwordLabel);
        centerPanel.add(passwordField);
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        southPanel.add(loginBtn);

        // JDialog
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, northPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, centerPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, southPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE /* not valid for a JDialog JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE*/);
        //add modality to wait for the frame to close
        frame.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //set frame to visible after it has been completely set
        //including its modality
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Validate1 Class
    //can be implemented a simple methos
    //static class Validate1 implements ActionListener
    private void validate1()
    {

        String username = null;
            String password = null;

            try
            {
                username = usernameField.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
                password = passwordField.getText().toUpperCase().trim();

                if (username.equals("") && password.equals(""))
                {
                    usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (username.equals(""))
                    {
                        usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                        passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (password.equals(""))
                        {
                            usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
                            passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                            passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.red);

                            //no need to initialize Login again
                            //new Login().validate2(username, password);
                            validate2(username, password);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception validateError)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was an error Class::Login Class Validate1", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
    }

    //Validate2 Method
    private void validate2(String getUsername, String getPassword)
    {
        String username = null;
        String password = null;

        try
        {
            username = getUsername.toUpperCase();
            password = getPassword.toUpperCase();

            //the validation logic needs to be revised 
            if (username.contains(" ") && password.contains(" "))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The username and password is invalid", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else
            {
                if (username.contains(" "))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The username is invalid", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (password.contains(" "))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The password is invalid", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                        passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                        System.out.println("All good!!");

                        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
                        //set return value to indicate successful login
                        loginSuccess = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in Class::Login Method:valsidate2","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
    }
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask where you need clarifications.

Comment: Hi c0der, thanks for the tips.  Just trying to get my head round this then, the logic for the read class needs to be implemented in the validate2 method, would pass the username and password to those classes to have them checked?

Comment: I would say that the read class should be called from validate 2.